# Connect column of nodes based on another column

Tags: python, pandas, networkx

I would need to build a network where nodes are websites and should be grouped based on a score assigned. If the website is new, then it will have a label 1, otherwise 0.

Example of data:

```
url          score             label
web1           5                 1
web2           10                1
web3           5                 0
web4           2                 0
...
```

I tried to use networkx to build the net. To group together the webs based on their score, I just used score as a common node (but probably there would be a better way to represent it).
I would like to colour the webs based on label column, but I do not know how to do that.
My code is:

```
import networkx as nx

G = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, 'url', 'score')


nodes = G.nodes()
plt.figure(figsize=(40,50)) 
pos = nx.draw(G, with_labels=True, 
              nodelist=nodes,
              node_size=1000)
```

I hope you can give me some tips.

Comment: sorry for the delay in accepting and upvoting it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably a partition graph might be a good idea if you want to include the `score` as a node too. You can start by creating the graph with `nx.from_pandas_edgelist` as you did, and update the node attributes as:

```
B = nx.from_pandas_edgelist(df, source='url', target='score')

node_view = B.nodes(data=True)
for partition_nodes, partition in zip((df.url, df.score), (0,1)):
    for node in partition_nodes.to_numpy():
        node_view[node]['bipartite'] = partition
```

Now we have the partition attributes for each node:

```
B.nodes(data=True)
NodeDataView({'web1': {'bipartite': 0}, 5: {'bipartite': 1}, 'web2': 
{'bipartite': 0}, 10: {'bipartite': 1}, 'web3': {'bipartite': 0}, 
'web4': {'bipartite': 0}, 2: {'bipartite': 1}})
```

The graph can be represented with a partition layout:

```
part1_nodes = [node for node, attr in B.nodes(data=True) if attr['bipartite']==0]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(12,8))
plt.box(False)
nx.draw_networkx(
    B,
    pos = nx.drawing.layout.bipartite_layout(B, part1_nodes),
    node_color=[]
    node_size=800)
```

[image]